# convert std::u16string to NSString

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

In my Native Library I used to have this function to return a `NSString` out of a `std::string`:

```
- (NSString*)return_my_cpp_string {
    NSString* result = [NSString stringWithCString:my_cpp_string.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    return result;
}
```

I now need to update this function so that it rather returns a `NSString` out of an `std::u16string` but I can't find any obvious way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`stringWithCharacters:length`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497248-stringwithcharacters) instead of `stringWithCString:encoding`.

`stringWithCharacters` takes a pointer to a C-style array of UTF-16 code units as input. `std::u16string` is a UTF-16 encoded string, so you can use its data as-is, eg:

```
- (NSString*)return_my_cpp_string {
    const unichar *pchars = (const unichar *) my_cpp_string.c_str();
    NSString* result = [NSString stringWithCharacters:pchars length:my_cpp_string.size()];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I get a `Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const unichar * _Nonnull' (aka 'const unsigned short *') with an rvalue of type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char16_t, std::__1::char_traits<char16_t>, std::__1::allocator<char16_t> >::value_type *' (aka 'const char16_t *')` error

Comment: I can fix this with a `(const unichar*)` cast and it'd work OK - just wandering if that's OK to do ?

Comment: @MarinosK yes, that is what you would need to do. I have updated my answer.